# Save data as text file from spark to hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-hive

I processed data using `pySpark` and `sqlContext` using the following query:

```
(sqlContext.sql("select LastUpdate,Count(1) as Count" from temp_t)
           .rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("/apps/hive/warehouse/Count"))
```

It is stored in the following format:

```
Row(LastUpdate=u'2016-03-14 12:27:55.01', Count=1)
Row(LastUpdate=u'2016-02-18 11:56:54.613', Count=1)
Row(LastUpdate=u'2016-04-13 13:53:32.697', Count=1)
Row(LastUpdate=u'2016-02-22 17:43:37.257', Count=5)
```

But I want to store the data in a Hive table as

```
LastUpdate                           Count

2016-03-14 12:27:55.01                   1
.                                        .
.                                        .
```

Here is how I create the table in Hive:

```
CREATE TABLE Data_Count(LastUpdate string, Count int )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED fields terminated by '|';
```

I tried many options but was not successful. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not load the data into Hive itself, without going through the process of saving the file and then loading it to hive.

```scala
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
hiveCtx = HiveContext(sc)

#Create sample data
currTime = datetime.now()
currRow = Row(LastUpdate=currTime)
delta = timedelta(days=1)
futureTime = currTime + delta
futureRow = Row(LastUpdate=futureTime)
lst = [currRow, currRow, futureRow, futureRow, futureRow]

#parallelize the list and convert to dataframe
myRdd = sc.parallelize(lst)
df = myRdd.toDF()
df.registerTempTable("temp_t")
aggRDD = hiveCtx.sql("select LastUpdate,Count(1) as Count from temp_t group by LastUpdate")
aggRDD.saveAsTable("Data_Count")
```

Comment: thanks , used the same approach..but the data is stored as                 2016-03-14 12:27:55.01    1
2016-02-18 11:56:54.613 1                                                                         not as table format... with columns names and i cannot query like we do on table ex: dl commands

Comment: can you please post a sample dl commands that wouldn't work here?

Answer (score 0):

You created a table, now you need to fill it with the data you generated.

This could be ran from a Spark HiveContext, I believe

```sql
LOAD DATA INPATH '/apps/hive/warehouse/Count' INTO TABLE Data_Count
```

Alternatively, you may want to build a table over the data

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT Exists Data_Count(
    LastUpdate DATE, 
    Count INT
   ) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/apps/hive/warehouse/Count';
```

Comment: I stored result to one variable (ex:result) in spark, after running the above query, when i did result.show()...data displayed in 2 columns with pipe as seperator.  yes, i did "LOAD DATA INPATH '/apps/hive/warehouse/Count' INTO TABLE Data_Count" but result showing  under one column "LastUpdate" both date and count, and other column "Count" showing as NULL.

Comment: When you show an RDD, it formats with a pipe. It does not save data to a text file with a pipe. You can cat the HDFS file to inspect the actual delimiter. You are getting null in the second column because everything is shoved to the first column

Comment: Hello, checked..its delimited by "," and when i changed your query accordingly and executed now i am getting both the columns as NULL